# AUDIT command on Oracle 11g standard edition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, audit

I want to audit 2 tables (select,insert,update,delete) on an Oracle 11g standard edition.

Someone told me, that the AUDIT command is just allowed with the enterprise edition.

Is it possible **with a Oracle 11g standard edition and without paying for additional licences**?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL command AUDIT is part of the Standard Edition.

Anything not explicitly mentioned in the Licensing Guide is included in the Standard Edition.  As you can see, only Fine-Grained Audit is restricted to the Enterprise Edition.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/license.111/b28287/editions.htm#CJACGHEB).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether AUDIT in an Enterprise Edition feature or not, but another approach would be to use triggers to audit the DML commands (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)

Auditing SELECTs would be trickier.  You could maybe fudge something using virtual columns, but I suspect it'd be fairly messy.

Comment: yes, using triggers would be another possibility to easily setup logging for (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE). But i don't know how to audit select queries. can you tell me more about virtual columns?